# Runtime reflection: getting variables and/or scopes from an AST

Tags: scala, reflection, abstract-syntax-tree

Consider the following function declaration (pretty trivial in this case, but the question of course applies to the general case):

```
def f( x : Int ) = { val y = 1; val z = 2; x * y * z }
```

Given the Tree obtained for f by runtime reflection, is there any built-in support for

a) getting the variable declarations?

b) their associated scopes?

I can see that one can obtain a) by writing a custom tree traverser, and then b) by performing further traversals from the point of declaration.

However, this is clearly a nontrivial and error-prone undertaking.

In particular, I see that the reflection API contains a Scope class, but am unable to determine whether this plays any role in providing for b).